# Responsive image inserted with css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm having an issue with one of my joomla website. I'm using sobi to display a map of outlets available in the shopping mall. And I want to make this map responsive. The problem is that this map is an image inserted with css :

HTML :

```
<div id="system">
    <article class="item">
      <div class="content clearfix">
        <div id="plan-boutiques">
          <img src="..."></img> <!-- This is the points on the map not the map -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#plan-boutiques {
  background: url(../images/rom/niveau.png) no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 374px;
  width: 685px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Then when I change the width, the image is cropped and not resized as it would be if I had the image in an img tag. I can't change this, the image as to be added with css. I hope there's a way to make it responsive !

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain;`?

Comment: Yes I tried this, forgot to mention, but yes I tried and the image is cropped either way

Comment: Wop forgot it ! It works with contain ! Thank you I didn't know such a property existed ;)

Comment: I've made my comment an answer so you have something to mark.  Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `#plan-boutiques` rule:

```
#plan-boutiques {
    background: url(../images/rom/niveau.png) no-repeat top center / contain;
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make responsive don't apply any fixed with and height. No need to apply width and height. Use this width and height in this way.

```
#plan-boutiques > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 685px;
  max-height: 374px;
 }
```

Comment: height: auto; would not effect the displaying the img. Then may be this div section floated not in correct way.

Comment: I'm telling you what I see. It's a but complicated since I don't manage all the parts (Thanks Joomla ..)

Comment: The image is set in css, not in a img div